# the python bot using selenium to locate searchbar in linkedin is not working

Tags: python, xpath, bots, linkedin-api, locate

I tried to make a linkedin login bot using python and selenium, but face 2 problems. I can login the page, however, the page closes immediately. Secondly, i could not find the correct xpath key word to locate the search button in linkedin. I tried many xpath keywords, but dint help. i checked the linkedin source code, i could not find which is related to the search bar in the html codes. i am a newbie to python and bots.

I am using Chrome - 120.0.6099.110, Selenium - 4.15.2.

[image]